# Possible to programmatically force timer to run?

Tags: managed-metadata, timer-jobs, development

I've exposed some 'rename metadata term' functionality to the user through an application page. It works fine, but they obviously don't see the changes until the 'Taxonomy Update Scheduler' has ran - can I make it run instead of just telling them they'll have to wait?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can call [SPJobDefinition.RunNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.administration.spjobdefinition.runnow.aspx) on the right timer job